# Why can't I see my other partitions on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, partition-recovery

I have installed Windows 10 on UEFI mode but I only see my C drive. I remember I created 2 other drives and it created also 3 or 4 other drives automatically but what I see is only C. I also remember when I created D and E partitions it was written `primary` in front of them.

[image]

EDIT: I did a right-click on RAW partitions and choose format->NTSF and converted them successfully but still can't see them in This PC.

Comment: Right-click the Start button, select _Disk Management_ and include a screenshot in your question ([edit] it).

Comment: @gronostaj: I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign drive letters to your other partitions.

1. Right-click the Start button, select *Disk Management*. Wait until it loads.
2. Right-click partition next to *C:* which doesn't have a drive letter displayed. Select *Change Drive Letter and Paths*.
3. Click *Add* and select any letter to assign. Confirm with *OK*.

Then repeat for the second partition.

Comment: Thank you. Should I do anything for `Disk 0 partition 2` that has 100MB volume?

Comment: No - that's the EFI partition. Don't touch.

Comment: If your EFI partition is configured properly, Windows won't let you do anything with it. It's a system partition required to boot. It doesn't contain any user-modifiable files.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my laptop to a 2TB SSD with 2 partitions and windows 10. The first of 100GB for the operating system and other programs, the second purely for file storage. Finally (thanks to Google) managed to convert my drive to a GPT format and set the partition.  Disk Management shows them as 100GB (C drive) 450mb Healthy (Recovery Partition) 100MB Healthy (EFI System Partition and finally 1690.3GB (E Drive)  Likewise I was told to leave the 2 small drives alone (Those that have no drive letter assigned)